# errors messages with html and php

Tags: php, html, validation

i have this code bellow:

```
if($name !=null && $email !=null && $password !=null && $gender !=null) {
   if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailError = "you should write a correct email";
   }
   if(strlen($password) < 6) {
    $passwordError = "password should consist from 6 charachters or more";
   }
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if($result) {
    header("location:index.php");
   }else {
    echo "Error";
   }
} else {
    $msg = "you should fill all the form";
}
}
```

it doesn't show any error when the email is not correct or the password is less than 6, and inserts data normally, I need to show for example two error messages if both password and email are not correct, how can I do it?

Comment: Where did you get this code ?

Comment: I created it by myself

Comment: You're not output any error messages. You only assign some variables with error messages. You should at least use `echo $emailError` and `echo $passwordError`... But that's not enough. You have to manage the situations when these errors occurs. For example, should you exit your code? Forward to another page? Error throwing? Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend your code so that

1. it will NOT execute the db query if there is/are error(s)
2. Display the errors if they exist.

```
<?php

//initialize the error messages to be blank

$emailError ="";
$passwordError="";

if($name !=null && $email !=null && $password !=null && $gender !=null) {
     if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         $emailError = " you should enter a correct email ;";
      }
      if(strlen($password) < 6) {
          $passwordError = " password should consist of 6 characters or more ;";
      }

if ($emailError =="" && $passwordError=="") {

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if($result) {
       header("location:index.php");
      } else {
       echo "Error";
      }

} else {

echo "You have the following error(s) :";  

  if ($emailError !=""){
    echo $emailError;
  }

  if ($passwordError !=""){
    echo $passwordError;
  }
}


} else {
//    $msg = "you should fill all the form";
    echo "you should enter all the required data in the form";
}


?>
```